# Android Time picker Send Time to PHP Mysql Server

Tags: android, phpmyadmin, timepicker

I want to send current time to my database can anyone solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously DATETIME, DATE, TIME etc are set to its relevant Date and Time datatypes. Now to make this table we open up the MySQL terminal and enter the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dt_tb` ( `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `dt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', `dt2` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00', UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`), UNIQUE KEY `id_2` (`id`), UNIQUE KEY `id_3` (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Note that here we have used a custom database date_time to store this table.

Now your android coding for getting data and time is

Then I created a function that uses this format and converts the current date and returns a string with the current date in this format. Here is the complete code.

```
1. Step 1: import the required classes

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

2. Step 2: Initialize the variables

public static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

3. Step 3: create the function to get current date and convert to the above format

public static String now() {
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
return sdf.format(cal.getTime());

}
```

Now php coding for inserting date and time in mysql is here:

```
<?Php
require "config.php"; // Database Connection
$dt1=date("Y-m-d");
$dt2=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$sql="INSERT INTO dt_tb(dt,dt2) VALUES ('$dt2', '$dt1')";
$sql=$dbo->prepare($sql);
if($sql->execute()){
echo " Date stored in table ";
}
else{
echo " Not able to add record ";
print_r($sql->errorInfo());
}

?>
```

So these is procedure for inserting date time in php and mysql using android , and for connecting android to php please follow these tutorial here is link :-https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/php-android-tutorial-part-1/

Comment: Thanks i got a bit idea if any issue occurs i will ask >